# Como quitar la línea molesta que aparece entre dos <div>?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, div

Me refiero ah este espacio que esta entre estos dos DIV, tambien me gustaria saber a que se debe esto, cual es la razón por la que aparece, ¿esto es algun estilo predeterminado por algun navegador?, también si esto afecta de forma que al asignar un 50% de ancho a dos cajas estas no acaparan mitad y mitad en el viewport y en lugar de esto da un salto de linea la siguiente caja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo HMTL es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/uwu.css">
    <title>uwu</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="padre" >
        <div class="padre__div padre__div--grey"></div>
        <div class="padre__div  padre__div--red"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

y el codigo CSS es el siguiente:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

br{
    height: 0; width: 0;
}

.padre{
    width: 100%;
}

.padre__div{
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    display : inline-block;
}


.padre__div--grey{
    background-color: grey;
}

.padre__div--red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Prueba eliminando `display : inline-block`

Comment: Tienes que quitar el padding = 0%;

Comment: chicos , ninguno de los dos ah servido .  ,   u  .

Comment: @OwOscarxD quita el border box

Answer (score 2):

con el display: inline-block lo que haces es alinear tus dos divs pero crea esa separación entre ellos, aunque no lo tengas definidos.

Una solución rápida que puedes hacer es esto:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

br{
    height: 0; width: 0;
}

.padre{
    width: 100%;
}

.padre__div{
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    //display : block;
}


.padre__div--grey{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}

.padre__div--red{
    background-color: red;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>uwu</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="padre" >
        <div class="padre__div padre__div--grey"></div>
        <div class="padre__div  padre__div--red"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Pero depende de qué necesites hacer igual, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar flexbox también, has que el contenedor sea un display:flex escoge la dirección de los items que tendrá en su interior flex-direction: row . Puedes profundizar un poco en otras propiedades flexbox que te harán todo mas fácil.

```css
.padre{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.padre-div-grey{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 50%;
}
.padre-div-red{
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/uwu.css">
    <title>uwu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="padre">
        <div class="padre-div-grey"></div>
        <div class="padre-div-red"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```